# DDD aggregates as a public api

Tags: domain-driven-design

Im a bit confused as to how I should be thinking of my domain aggregate roots. Basically they seem to me as a public api for the client to use which hides the implementation of the aggregate roots children.

so for example if Foo is the aggregate root and Bar is a child entity. If I want the aggregate to perform some sort of action which Bar is involved in then its okay to call methods similar to:

```
(inside foo class)
void SomeBarThing()
{
  this.Bar.DoTheBarThing()
}
```

and that's basically it? The client only knows and cares about the aggregate root because it functions as sort of a GOF facade pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that's basically it?

Yes and no.

Yes, you are mostly right about the information hiding.  The application only knows the interface of the root entity, and the root entity decides what work to do for itself and what work to delegate to other entities in the same aggregate.

> Im a bit confused as to how I should be thinking of my domain aggregate roots.

The Evans 2003 book is some help here.  ENTITY is a domain modeling pattern (Chapter 5); AGGREGATES are a *life cycle management* pattern (Chapter 6).

Basic idea: the aggregate is a graph of entities that model some part of the domain.

But in the Evans formulation, the aggregate doesn't have an interface of its own.  Instead, one of the entities in the graph is "promoted" to be the root object, to which all of the information is sent.